# If I divide a recursive call by another, would I get an infinite loop?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm experimenting with recursion in Java and I have this method:

```
public static int recursion(int n) {
    if(n==1) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        int test = (recursion(n-1))/(recursion(n-1));
        return test;
    }
}
```

If I run it with `n = 50`, it never prints anything, so I'm guessing the recursive calls are infinite? Could anybody explain why?

Comment: Then you would see a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu The memory usage is not an issue. The recursion depth is only ~50.

Answer (score 12):

It is not infinite, just huge. You will do roughly 2^50 recursive calls. Even if each call takes just one nanosecond (which is much too low) this means a total run time of about two weeks.

Comment: The explanation using a nanosecond is on spot!

Answer (score 8):

Here, `recursion()` is called like a binary tree

```
recursion(50) -> recursion(49) -> recursion(48) ...
                                  recursion(48) ...
                 recursion(49) -> recursion(48) ...
                                  recursion(48) ...
```

So the binary tree height is 49.
Then `recursion()` is called: *total number of nodes of the tree* times. This equates to `2^(h+1)-1` = `2^(49+1)-1` =  `2^(50)-1`  times.
That's huge, which takes a very long time to execute. This is the problem, but it's not infinite.

You can instead do the following, which is not a problem because `recursion(n)` to `recursion(n-1)` is called only once:

```
public static int recursion(int n) {
    if(n==1) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        int test = recursion(n-1);
        test = test/test
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well explained.